# Django - call def on button click?

Tags: django, button, get, request, click

SO I have this simple button in my template:

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" value="8" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="print_btn">
</form>
```

In my views.py i have this function:

```
def print_from_button(request):

    if(request.GET.get('print_btn')):
        print( int(request.GET.get('mytextbox')) )
        print('Button clicked')
```

this prints to console:

> "GET /myview/mytextbox=8&print_btn=Click HTTP 1.1" 200

I also want '*Button clicked*' to be printed on the terminal, i.e. I want the function **print_from_button** executed, not just one statement in the function.

EDIT:

As suggested in the coments, i added a return, and changed the template:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="print_btn">
</form>
```

Added new function:

```
def hello():
    print('Hello!')
```

and return in my target function

```
def print_from_button(request):
    if(request.GET.get('print_btn')):
        hello()
        print('Button clicked')
    return render(request, 'new/click.html',{'value':'Button clicked'})
```

but it prints the same:

> "GET /myview/mytextbox=8&print_btn=Click HTTP 1.1" 200

SOLVED:
I forgot to add the function **print_from_button** in urls.py!

Thanks everyone who contributed.

Comment: Seems like your if condition is not met. Add an else and print something in case `request.GET.get('print_btn')` evaluates to `false`

Comment: I added: **else: print('not')** nothing happens...

Comment: Can you please add your `urls.py` - what you show as output is just the default logging from `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: You are right, i totally forgot to call it from urs.py!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to be rendered back, must return render -
    `return render(request, 'your-template.html',{})`, so it will be

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def print_from_button(request):

    if(request.GET.get('print_btn')):
        print( int(request.GET.get('mytextbox')) )
        print('Button clicked')
    return render(request, 'your-template.html',{'value':'Button clicked'})
```

Then on the client side - in the inspector's console, or whatever tool you use, you'll see 'Button clicked' set in `value`. 
Make sure `your-template.html` (or whatever name you prefer) exists in the templates directory configured for your Django project.

Comment: Thats it, i want to see printed in it in terminal, i dont need the return. I want the print statement, or some other function executed on the server side...

Comment: But you *must* return a response, that is the contract for a view. It can be empty if you like but it needs to be an HttpResponse or subclass.